# library for drawing xy-chart in UWP

Tags: uwp, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

Which chart libraries for UWP (best free) can draw xy-chart?
I meant chart which:

- draws line between sequential points: p0, p1, p2, ...
- x-axis is not a simple series of values: 1,2,3,4..

Example data:

```
x 1.0 2.4 5.6 ...
y 2.4 3.5 1.2
```

I tried `WinRT XAML Toolkit` but it seems it supports only simple series in x-axix (I mean values: 1,2,3,4..).

Answer (score 1):

[OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot) or [Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radchart/cartesianchart/series/scatter-series/skatter-scatterlineseries), both are free.